# Fail to connect Mongoose to Atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-mongodb-native, mongodb-atlas

I'm always connecting to the "admin" DB, which is a [fixed bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-1286).

Using Mongoose 5.0.6 MongoDb 3.6 and trying to connect to Atlas.

1. My question, what driver Mongoose 5.0.6 depend on?
2. How can I find out when Mongoose will have that fix?
3. On a different direction, is there a way to connect with MongoDB then use this connection with
   Mongoose?

Cheers

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Basically you should try connecting with your url link, and specify the DB name on the mongoose connect method
so if your cluster link is:

```
mongodb+srv://userName:Passwrod@clustor.mongodb.net/
```

and your DB name is:

```
testDB
```

then you should call the mongoose.connect method as follows:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://userName:Passwrod@cluster.mongodb.net/', {dbName: 'testDB'});
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting this error :/  events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: No valid replicaset instance servers found

Comment: @MisirJafarov are you trying to connect to an atlas instance which have replicasets?

Comment: @ChaiHalfon sorry but actually I don't know what's replicaset :/ I'm new to MongoDB.

Comment: i fixed it by updating mongoose

Answer (score 3):

Connection is established when you use this connection string for (MongoShell 3.6+) :

```
var connDB = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster-fax0w.mongodb.net/test"
```

However, you will not be able to read/write data without entering the DBName in the mongoose.connect().

```
mongoose.connect(uri, { dbName: <your DB name> })
  .then( () => {
    console.log('Connection to the Atlas Cluster is successful!')
  })
  .catch( (err) => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a side note if you ever get an error connecting to the MongoDB Atlas make sure:

1. You've whitlisted our IP address / all (0.0.0.0/0)
2. Your credentials are right
3. Firewall / anti-virus are disabled

And if all fails

1. Make sure your DNS is a public one. Or maybe change it to Google's public DNS.
   Throwing a link for the same:
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F9u5ULrRt3Y

Goodluck!