# MERN stack - invalid mongodb uri

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a MERN stack application on Heroku based on the mern.io boilerplate code, and to do so I was following this tutorial that is based on the same boilerplate code: https://github.com/jeffreynerona/mern-io-heroku.

I'm currently trying to link my MongoDB cluster to my application, so I used the exact URI generated by MongoDB and I ended with the following code:

```
const config = {
  mongoURL: process.env.MONGO_URL || 'mongodb+srv://sam:sam1@cluster0-qnroe.mongodb.net/mern-starter',
  port: process.env.PORT || 8000,
};

export default config;
```

However, this gave me the following error: Error: `Invalid mongodb uri "mongodb+srv://sam:sam1@cluster0-qnroe.mongodb.net/mern-starter". Must begin with "mongodb://"`.

Just as reference, when I was hosting my application locally everything ran as it should. The rest of the code in the block above was the same, except the URI I had for that was `mongodb://localhost:27017/mern-starter`. Any thoughts would be appreciated on why this new URI is giving me an error!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fail to connect Mongoose to Atlas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48917591/fail-to-connect-mongoose-to-atlas)

Comment: You need the 3.x version of the node driver in order to use `mongodb+srv`. If you cloned this project from someone's github repo then it's likely a 2.x driver. Just use the `mongodb://` option instead, and optionally with `replicaSet` appended if you have one. There should be an option to copy this from the Atlas console.