# MongoDB connection bug

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm currently learning MongoDB, and I'm trying to connect to my database by MongoDB ATLAS
but I'm getting trouble which I couldn't yet connect to it

here is the code:

```
    mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://anis:anisninis@cluster.mongodb.net/',
    { 
        dbName: 'testDB',
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    })
    .then(() => console.log('Connexion à MongoDB réussie !'))//you are connected
    .catch(() => console.log('Connexion à MongoDB échouée !'));// you aren't
```

the output: `you are not connected to MongoDB`

Comment: sorry ! but i didn't understand what you mean  can you please explain more

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The error is coming from the commands **after** the shown code, because nothing is blocking up to then ;-) Try `await mongoose.connect(...)`. Also if those are your real credentials, you should change them by now.

Comment: here is the url    :  mongodb+srv://anis:<password>@cluster0.knyha.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority                            so i don"t know my dbname so i followed this one                                                                                   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48917591/fail-to-connect-mongoose-to-atlas/48917626#48917626